# Springboot No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource]

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to use application.properties to bean datasource but it seems that spring boot does not find the file or something like.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Here my structure:

```
 .
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── companies
        │           ├── CompanyApplication.java
        │           ├── config
        │           │   └── WebMvcConfig.java
        │           ├── controller
        │           │   └── HelloWorldController.java
        │           └── model
        │               ├── Article.java
        │               ├── daoInterface
        │               │   └── ArticleDaoInterface.java
        │               ├── daoTemplates
        │               │   └── ArticleDao.java
        │               └── mappers
        │                   └── ArticleMapper.java
        ├── resources
        │   └── application.properties
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── pages
                    └── hello.jsp
```

I've try to move application.properties file from resources to config and nothing. 
`application.properties:`

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/name
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            //Required repos
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
            maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        }
        dependencies {
            //Required dependency for spring-boot plugin
            classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.6.RELEASE"
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

    jar {
        baseName = 'companies'
        version = '0.2'
    }

    war {
        baseName = 'companies'
        version =  '0.1'
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
        compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.2.6.RELEASE')
        testCompile("junit:junit")
        //Required dependency for JSP
        compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
    }
```

And where I'm trying to autowire the dataSource:

```
package com.companies.model.daoTemplates;

import com.companies.model.Article;
import com.companies.model.daoInterface.ArticleDaoInterface;
import com.companies.model.mappers.ArticleMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class ArticleDao implements ArticleDaoInterface {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

    private final String DB_NAME = "articles";

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Article> listArticle() {
        String SQL = "select * from " + DB_NAME + " where inactive = false ORDER BY name";
        List <Article> article = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL,
                new ArticleMapper());
        return article;
    }

}
```

`CompanyApplication.java`

```
package com.companies;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class CompanyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CompanyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I cannot find where I'm failing at.

Comment: Show `CompanyApplication`

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using? Do you have `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` in your dependency list and do you have the MySQL driver present?

Comment: @M.Deinum was right, I had one dependency left spring-boot-starter-jdbc. Now I'm having problems with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
`Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: That's it, another dependency left, sorry

Comment: @M.Deinum can yo reply to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967143/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-javax-sql-datasource-is-defined. Its same think but I am getting where is the issue ?

Answer (score 9):

As [@M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) mentioned in his comment it seems to be a dependency configuration problem. [You need a dependency on spring-jdbc for an embedded database to be auto-configured](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html).

Please make sure you've followed on the  [documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/)

You should also check out this [spring-boot-jdb sample](http://xantorohara.blogspot.ca/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-sample.html)

Comment: Any guidance for the project with nosql? How we can solve this ? Why do we need to put JDBC in pom in case on NOSQL ?

Answer (score 6):

I got a similar error and I solved it by adding the following dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

Spring boot is mostly based on the principle than putting a specific jar in the classpath will trigger the activation of the related functionality. Spring boot is scanning the classpath at startup and will start "everything he found" except if you disable it by using annotation.

So to have Spring Boot initializing a DataSource you must have one of the following dependencies:
- spring-boot-starter-jdbc : will allow to use the DataSource and JDBC stuff.
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa : will load the JPA and so the DataSource as a sub-module

Answer (score 1):

This should be the correct declaration of your runner class:

```
package com.companies;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CompanyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(
            SpringApplication.run(CompanyApplication.class, args)));
    }

}
```

Amidst other things, it will auto-initialize your `DataSource` from the `application.properties`.

**EDIT**: in your `application.properties` you should have entries similar to these, which are specific for an Oracle DataSource:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostaddr>:<port>:<instance_name>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem and figured out that implementation of DataSource is placed in Tomcat libs. So for 8th tomcat you going to include `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` class that placed in `org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.36`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I solved it by adding the dependency for the mysql java connector.

Comment: You should probably be more specific with how did you add the dependency and/or how you figured what dependency to add.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know how to answer here. I figured what dependency to add because you need the mysql java connector in Spring to connect to mySQL-databases. And he knows how to add dependencies. He has already added several in his project. Everybody has who has come this far...

Comment: If it's a common thing, then it's ok. I have no experience with Java, just was reviewing first answers, so appologize if the commen was irrelevant