# No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Here is my pom**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Here is my main class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Here is my application.properties**

```
#server.contextPath=/SpringBootExamples
server.port=8888
logging.file=F:/new-spring-boot/Test-Spring-Boot.log

# spring security configuration
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=admin1
management.security.role=SUPERUSER
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springbootdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

**Here is my UserServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl  implements UserService{

     @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(MyUserEntity user) {
        userRepo.save(user);
        //testTransaction();
    }
}
```

**Here is my UserRepository **

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<MyUserEntity, Long>{


}
```

i am getting below error while `java -jar target/example-spring-boot-rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService javabeat.net.springboot.config.WebSecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySpringUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final javabeat.net.springboot.service.UserService javabeat.net.springboot.service.MySpringUserDetailsService.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:F:\new-spring-boot\target\example-spring-boot-rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/javabeat/net/springboot/service/UserServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javabeat.net.springboot.dao.UserRepository]: : Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#188ad80b' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#188ad80b': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#188ad80b' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#188ad80b': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
```

Comment: You is using `example-spring-boot-rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`, where declared `UserServiceImpl` bean. This bean is using `EntitiyManager` bean, that in turn, is using `DataSource` bean. But `DataSource` bean is not defined.

Comment: I am not using EntityManager explicitly in my application. See my updated post

Comment: You starter version is pretty outdated `1.0.1.RELEASE`. I had strange behaviour then one of my spring dependency was from different version. Can you update to the latest `spring-boot 1.3.3`?

Comment: @emilly you are not, but Repository does: `Error creating bean with name 'userRepository'`. `DataSource` bean is needed.

Comment: @KenBekov so what I need to do  ?

Comment: Obviously, data source bean didn't created automatically. I don't know why. You can try create it manually, just to check - is this problem of data source bean or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded to

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

It worked fine. **But its really strange** as it was working with  version `1.0.1.` also till one hour before.

Comment: That is really common.   There are a lot of great things with Spring Boot, but  all the auto magical stuff makes it REALLY fragile.   Making the smallest change to a config or annotation can cause it all to come falling down.

Answer (score 2):

I was using 1.3.6 release and then changed back to 1.3.3 . It worked for me