# Build failure on spring boot + react + mysql connector?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am currently creating a project on spring boot + react (autoloading) + mysql database, but once I try to create the backend like [this tuto](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql), I get this error

> Error creating bean with name org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

My pom.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.gmed</groupId>
<artifactId>starter</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Spring Boot and React starter</name>
<description>Spring Boot and React starter</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version><!-- 1.3.3.RELEASE for the last stable release -->
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <orika-core.version>1.4.6</orika-core.version>
    <assertj-core.version>3.2.0</assertj-core.version>
    <lombok.version>1.16.6</lombok.version>
    <cobertura-plugin.version>2.7</cobertura-plugin.version>
    <coveralls-plugin.version>4.0.0</coveralls-plugin.version>
    <frontend-plugin.version>0.0.27</frontend-plugin.version>
    <node.version>v5.7.0</node.version>
    <npm.version>3.7.1</npm.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot Starters -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- We use HikariCP instead -->
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Other -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>

</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
        <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
        <version>${orika-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Cobertura -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cobertura-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <format>xml</format>
                <maxmem>256m</maxmem>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                <instrumentation>
                    <!-- Exclude JPA meta-model generated classes -->
                    <ignores>
                        <ignore>**/*_.java</ignore>
                    </ignores>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*_.class</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </instrumentation>
                <check/>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Coveralls -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eluder.coveralls</groupId>
            <artifactId>coveralls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${coveralls-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <repoToken>your coveralls repository token goes here</repoToken>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Frontend -->
        <!-- Frontend -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${frontend-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
                <nodeDownloadRoot>https://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
                <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
                <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                        <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>webpack build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>webpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<!-- Repositories only needed if using a milestone or snapshot -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I tried all the solutions on the web.

Thanks

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810178/springboot-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-javax-sql-datasource, Do you have spring-boot-starter-jdbc in your dependency list and do you have applciation.properties properly created?

Comment: show log  : mvn dependency:tree    ?

Comment: He shouldn't need a starter-jdbc if he's got starter-data-jpa.

Answer (score 0):

Spring will generate that error message if it cannot find the datasource parameters with which to build a datasource. Those parameters come from your application.properties (based on that tutorial you linked to). The most likely cause is that it's not loading the application.properties.

Without showing any of your code it's not possible to give a more detailed answer.